# devenv /setup resets the registry but I need a registry setting

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation, vspackage

Is there an alternative to devenv /setup in order to install my Package in VS2013?

My installer runs devenv /setup from a custom action at the end of the install.
However my build machine which creates the installer requires a particular VS2013 registry entry described here due to a [VS2013 bug](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d).

Is there and alternative to /setup?
/installVSTemplates worked from me in VS2010 but does not seem to be enough for VS2013!

Comment: Hard to guess why you are doing this.  Modifying the VS configuration on a build machine is generally a very bad idea.  Just use it to build, test it on QA machine.

Comment: As said its a VS2013 bug related to the Setup projects. Change is necessary to anyone building Setup installer projects from msbuild.